# How to print these letters out in depth first search format

Tags: java, depth-first-search

How to print these letters out in depth first search format
How do I make the output return the result: [a, c, e, b, d, g, f, h, j]
instead of [a, j, e, h, f, b, g, d, c]?
I think there is something wrong with my depthFirstTransversal method but I don’t know where.
My goal is to ultimately accept the input:
a c e j
e b f h
b d g
and get the result:
[a, c, e, b, d, g, f, h, j]

@Yunnosch I did my best, let me know what you think:
depthFirstTraversal takes the input graph and root and places it into a set

declares a LinkedHashSet Visited
and a stack called stack

pushes the root “a” onto the stack
while the stack isn’t empty:
String vertex = stack.pop() =“a”
If (visited doesn’t contain vertex)
Add vertex “a” to visited.
For(the vertex v: getAdjVertices(vertex) “a”. which takes a label as the input and returns a new vertex and arraylist
Stack.push(v.label)

I think my code returns a depth first search but I want it to return the results from first input to last, not last input to first. So if c e and j depend on a, I want it to return a c e j, not a j e c

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Graph {

    public static class GraphTraversal {
        static Set<String> depthFirstTraversal(Graph graph, String root) {
            Set<String> visited = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
            stack.push(root);
            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                String vertex = stack.pop();
                if (!visited.contains(vertex)) {
                    visited.add(vertex);
                    for (Vertex v : graph.getAdjVertices(vertex)) {
                        stack.push(v.label);
                    }
                }
            }
            return visited;
        }

        static Set<String> breadthFirstTraversal(Graph graph, String root) {
            Set<String> visited = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
            queue.add(root);
            visited.add(root);
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                String vertex = queue.poll();
                for (Vertex v : graph.getAdjVertices(vertex)) {
                    if (!visited.contains(v.label)) {
                        visited.add(v.label);
                        queue.add(v.label);
                    }
                }
            }
            return visited;
        }
    }
    private Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>> adjVertices;

    Graph() {
        this.adjVertices = new HashMap<Vertex, List<Vertex>>();
    }

    void addVertex(String label) {
        adjVertices.putIfAbsent(new Vertex(label), new ArrayList<>());
    }

    void removeVertex(String label) {
        Vertex v = new Vertex(label);
        adjVertices.values().stream().forEach(e -> e.remove(v));
        adjVertices.remove(new Vertex(label));
    }

    void addEdge(String label1, String label2) {
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex(label1);
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex(label2);
        adjVertices.get(v1).add(v2);
        adjVertices.get(v2).add(v1);
    }

    void removeEdge(String label1, String label2) {
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex(label1);
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex(label2);
        List<Vertex> eV1 = adjVertices.get(v1);
        List<Vertex> eV2 = adjVertices.get(v2);
        if (eV1 != null)
            eV1.remove(v2);
        if (eV2 != null)
            eV2.remove(v1);
    }

    List<Vertex> getAdjVertices(String label) {
        return adjVertices.get(new Vertex(label));
    }

    String printGraph() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for(Vertex v : adjVertices.keySet()) {
            sb.append(v);
            sb.append(adjVertices.get(v));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    class Vertex {
        String label;
        Vertex(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
            result = prime * result + ((label == null) ? 0 : label.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Vertex other = (Vertex) obj;
            if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
                return false;
            if (label == null) {
                if (other.label != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!label.equals(other.label))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return label;
        }


        private Graph getOuterType() {
            return Graph.this;
        }
    }
    static Graph createGraph() {
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        graph.addVertex("a");
        graph.addVertex("c");
        graph.addVertex("e");
        graph.addVertex("j");
        graph.addVertex("b");
        graph.addVertex("f");
        graph.addVertex("h");
        graph.addVertex("d");
        graph.addVertex("g");
        graph.addEdge("a", "c");
        graph.addEdge("a", "e");
        graph.addEdge("a", "j");
        graph.addEdge("e", "b");
        graph.addEdge("e", "f");
        graph.addEdge("e", "h");
        graph.addEdge("b", "d");
        graph.addEdge("b", "g");


        return graph;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph graph = createGraph();
        System.out.println(GraphTraversal.depthFirstTraversal(graph, "a"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a representation of the tree in question (ASCII art) and discuss why you expect the desired output and what the current output means for the traversal through the tree. Try to abstractly describe the systamatic mistake your code makes.

Comment: @Yunnosch I tried my best, lmk if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neighbors are added to the stack in your creation order and you want the graph to be traversed in that order, the ArrayList you create upholds that order but stack is LIFO which means that for an arbitrary node if a neighbor is added to the stack first, it is popped and processed last (for example if c as a neighbor of a is added to the stack first it is popped last, and j is visited first) so you have to add it last (in the reverse order) for it to be traversed first.

```
    if (!visited.contains(vertex)) {
        visited.add(vertex);
        List<Vertex> neighbors = graph.getAdjVertices(vertex);
        for (int i = neighbors.size()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
            Vertex v = neighbors.get(i);
            stack.push(v.label);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that in order to get the desired output, not OPs algorithm should be changed but instead the tree? Not sure that is a "legal" option.... Please consider what makes you think that it is the right approach. "It gets the desired output." I would not accept as sound reasoning.

Comment: The algorithm is correct although checking if the neighbor has not been visited before adding it is recommended. The "wrong" output that OP shows is a correct search just not in the order he wants.

Comment: So the desired output does not match the tree as OP creates it?

Comment: You're right the first answer is kinda ridiculous. Its that the neighbors of a are represented as [c, e, j] (The arraylist) but when they are added to the stack which is LIFO so when they are popped j is popped first, now a search where j is popped first is okay but to the OP its not so he should add c to the stack last if he wants it in that order.

Comment: thank you so much @Nima. I feel swamped right now trying to learn all of this but you guys have helped me a lot

Comment: I appreciate your comments on the first answer @Yunnosch. I tried modifying the input initially but decided I should try to fix the algorithm instead.

Comment: @Joshc, You're welcome. Everything is hard before it is easy.

Comment: @Joshc I first started coding at 12 but i didn't pursue it seriously. Currently I've finished my second semester at university in computer engineering major. I implemented BFS, DFS (iterative and recursive) for finding paths in a discrete mathematics course project i had this semester.

Comment: @Nima I think i need to take a semester off and review some of these concepts so i can get on your level haha. Which school are you attending?